# Check for valid token in order to update password

Tags: php, mysql, database, token

I've got two tables called 'members' and 'password_reset'. I've got a form (request-password.php) where users are able to reset their password by filling in their email. When they fill in the form, a link with a token has been send to the user email. The tokens are stored in the 'password_reset' table and all the usersinfo in the table 'members'

When the user clicks the link in the email, he'll be redirected to the reset-password.php page where he has to enter a new password and confirm it by filling it in again. After clicking the submit button, the page will redirect to update-password.php. This is the page with the code to update the new password to the database. However, before the page is able to update the database, it has to check whether the user has entered a password which is equal to the confirmpwd. Also whether the email and the assigned token are valid. If the entered passwords are equal and the token excist, it should update the user record of that specific user.

**My questions: How do I get the update-password.php file to check whether the email and the assigned token are valid, so the userrecord of the user with that email can be updated?
The email is stored in the 'members' table and the token in the 'password_reset'. I have no idea how to link them.**

This is my reset-password.php file

```
if (isset($_GET['token'])) { 
$uniqid = htmlentities( $_GET['token'] ); 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE token = '".$uniqid."' ");
if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) { 
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//Check Geldigheid token
$geldig = 7200;
if ( time()- intval( $row['tstamp'] ) > $geldig) {
//TOKEN HAS EXPIRED AND SUBMIT BUTTON HAS BEEN DISABLED
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wachtwoord Resetten</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/reset-wachtwoord.css' />
        <script type='text/JavaScript' src='../../js/sha512.js'></script> 
        <script type='text/JavaScript' src='../../js/forms.js'></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='container'>
    <div class='logo'></div>
    <div class='ww-vergeten-form'>
        <form action='' method=''>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='Nieuw Wachtwoord' size='50' maxlength='0'>
        <input type='password' name='confirmpwd' id='password' placeholder='Herhaal Wachtwoord' size='50' maxlength='0'>
        <input type='submit' class='reset-btn disabled' name='' value='Reset Wachtwoord' disabled></p>
        </form>
        <p class='error'>Sessie Verlopen. <a href='index.php'>Vraag een nieuwe aan</a>.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
";
} else {
//TOKEN IS STILL VALID
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wachtwoord Resetten</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/reset-wachtwoord.css' />
        <script type='text/JavaScript' src='../../js/sha512.js'></script> 
        <script type='text/JavaScript' src='../../js/forms.js'></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='container'>
    <div class='logo'></div>
    <div class='ww-vergeten-form'>
        <form action='password-changed.php' method='post'>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='Nieuw Wachtwoord' size='50' maxlength='255'>
        <input type='password' name='confirmpwd' id='password' placeholder='Herhaal Wachtwoord' size='50' maxlength='255'>
        <input type='submit' class='reset-btn' name='update' value='Reset Wachtwoord'></p>
        </form>
        <p class='nieuw-account'>Nog geen account? <a href='../../'>Maak er een aan</a>!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
";  
}

}else{
echo "<p class='error'>Token incorrect</p>";
}
}
```

**UPDATEEEEEEEEEEE!**
**@Chancho** - Alright I have updated my url in send-email.php to:

```
$url = "DOMAIN.COM/reset-password/reset.php?email=".$email."#token=".$uniqid;
```

Now the url isn't opening the webpage because I need to GET the $email, but since it's in a different table than the token, how do I get it?

Something like this?:

```
if (isset($_GET['token'])) { 
$uniqid = htmlentities( $_GET['token'] ); 
$email = htmlentities( $_GET['email'] ); 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE token = '".$uniqid."' ");
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '".$email."' ");
if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) { 
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,$result2);
}
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have for update-password.php, that's really what needs to be done.

Comment: *"I can't get the last part to work"* – And that's the `part` we need to see `update-password.php` your form is next to redundant. `$part="update-password.php";`

Comment: The only thing I can come up so far is, that I think your token may be interpreted as a string instead of an integer, which may or may not be the desired result. Give this a try `token = '$uniqid'` instead of `token = '".$uniqid."'` also try closing this with a semi-colon `value='<?php echo $uniqid; ?>'`

Comment: And use `var_dump($_GET);` or `var_dump($_GET['token']);` to see if anything is stored or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have edited my post to be more clear about what's going on and what I want.

Comment: You can use a `join` statement to get results from 2 tables. for example: ` SELECT * FROM password_reset preset WHERE token = $uniqid LEFT JOIN members mem ON preset.email = mem.email ' but probalby it would be better to use a userID to make this releation and not a email adres

Comment: I've got it and the password has been updated to the database. However, when a user signs up, the password will be saved as a encryped pass + a salt. I did the same for the new passwords.

Lets pretend I filled in the new password twice. I hit the update button and it updates the password row in the database with a new password, and the salt row with a new row. However, when I try to login, it wont let me.. It says invalid password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a releation between the email adres and the token ID:

1. User recieves token in his/her mailbox
2. user follows link and enters email address into webpage

reset-password.php (untested code):

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

//Don't forget to escape your query parameters
$token = $mysqli->real_escape_string($token);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE token = '$token' AND email = '$email'"));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{
    //user verified, update usertable
}
else
{
    //token or email invalid, show error to user
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. About your 2nd point, I don't want the user to fill in his/her email for a second time. I mean, he/she has already entered the email, which made her receive the email with the tokenlink. The user should be verified by then.

What I was thinkin about is the following: Adding $email to the form where it stores the token in the 'password_reset' table. So basically the users email will be stored in there. HOWEVER, when the user signed up, his email was inserted in the 'members' table. So dunno if thats a solution..

Comment: Then you can just send the email adres already within the link to reset-password.php and retrieve it with `$_GET['email']`

Comment: I probably think thats the best thing to do. So the link will look like: www.domain.com/reset?token=TOKENHEREemail=EMAILHERE. Then I can check whether the token is equal to the email. It doesn't care that the token is stored in another table than the email, right?